# Comparing post date get_the_date() from today - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to calculate the days that post was created and compare with today to echo "Today/ Yesterday/ Last Week/ Last Month".  The date format I get from get_the_date() is "December 1, 2015" so I'm wondering if I need to use a different function that I don't know about.

Comment: Have you checked out the formatting options for `the_time()`?  You'll probably need to write a little code to implement Today/Yesterday/etc... based on what that returns.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time#Examples

Answer (score 6):

You just need to the get_the_date() function;

Now Date Should In YYYY-MM-DD Format

for that

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(get_the_date())) ;
$current_date1 = date('Y-m-d', time()) ;
```

Now use this function

```
function dateDifference($date_1 , $date_2 )
{
    $datetime1 = date_create($date_1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_2);

    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

    return $interval->format('%a');

}

//call above function
echo $days = dateDifference($date1, $current_date1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is any WordPress function but you can get your values using built in PHP functions.

Yesterday:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day"));
```

Last week

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 week +1 day"));
```

Last month

```
date('Y-m-'.1, strtotime("-1 month")); //First day of -1 month
```

You can read more about strtotime here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Here is also a link to the date function, if you havent had any experience  with it before: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You would want to use Y-m-d format for wordpress querys read more about that here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php